# How to stop OLEDB to create "(sheet name)1" sheet automatically

Tags: excel, powershell, oledb, create-table

### Background

I am writing a PowerShell script to write some data to an Excel file (`.xlsx`) with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` like this:

```
$fileName = "C:\tmp\createtest.xlsx"
$sheetName = "record"
$provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
$dataSource = "Data Source = $fileName"
$extend = "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
$ddlSQL = "CREATE TABLE [$sheetName] (ID CHAR(4), NAME VARCHAR(20))"

$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$provider;$dataSource;$extend")

$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
$sqlCommand.Connection = $conn
$conn.open()

$sqlCommand.CommandText = $ddlSQL
$sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
...
$conn.close()
```

### Problem

When you create `C:\tmp\createtest.xlsx` with an empty sheet named `record` manually, the `CREATE TABLE` statement creates the `record1` sheet automatically.

I want to stop this behavior and let the `CREATE TABLE` statement throw an exception like ordinary RDBMS.

### Question

Is there any way to stop OLEDB to create the `(sheet name)1` sheet automatically when the Excel file has a sheet that has the same name?

Comment: Perhaps first do `"DROP TABLE [$sheetName]"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Execute `CREATE TABLE` with a suffix `$` for table name:

```
$ddlSQL = "CREATE TABLE [${sheetName}$] (ID CHAR(4), NAME VARCHAR(20))"
```

If the book and the sheet `record` already exists, this statement will be finished without error. If the book or the sheet `record` doesn't exist, This statement throws `OleDbException`. Either way, no new sheet will be created, so you can test the existence of the sheet safely.

If you want to use the sheet `record` regardless of existing sheet and avoid to create `record1` sheet automatically, you can do it like this:

```
$checkExistenceSQL = "CREATE TABLE [${sheetName}$] (ID CHAR(4), NAME VARCHAR(20))"
$ddlSQL = "CREATE TABLE [$sheetName] (ID CHAR(4), NAME VARCHAR(20))"

$conn.open()
try {
  try {
    # Check existing sheet and open if it exists
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $checkExistenceSQL
    $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > $null
  } catch {
    try {
      # Create new sheet if it doesn't exist
      $sqlCommand.CommandText = $ddlSQL
      $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > $null
    } catch {
      throw $PSItem
    }
  }

  $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO [${sheetName}$] VALUES (...)"
  $sqlCommand.CommandText = $insertSQL
  $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > $null
} finally {
  $conn.close()
}
```

Note that you have to execute `CREATE TABLE` first even if the sheet already exists because it affects the effectiveness of the datatype constraint. Also, you have to suffix the table name with `$` in the `INSERT` statement, because it fails if the sheet `record` already exists. See https://satob.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/11/24/003818 and https://satob.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/11/25/012835 for details.